# Linking DirectX

Tags: c++, directx-9

I am working on a DirectX9 project, and it is time now to start doing sprites, and to do so, I need d3dx9.h included, so after a while of trying to get it linked properly, which itself was confusing because it found d3d9.h just fine and its in the same location as d3dx9, I assumed that I would just need to add it to additional libraries, and after a while it finally worked. However upon running the program I get an error, from d3dx9core.h:

`C2061: syntax error: identifier 'TEXTMETRICA'`

I cannot find any answers online, and cannot figure out what is causing this problem. The line of code is 330 of d3dx9core.h, `STDMETHOD_(BOOL, GetTextMetricsA)(THIS_ TEXTMETRICA *pTextMetrics) PURE;` it comes with four errors, all pointing to this line. Any thoughts?

Comment: What Windows SDK and compiler are you using? D3D9 is pretty old, and I recall Microsoft creating a mess moving stuff around previously with XAudio2 at least (old DX SDK not working properly with modern Win SDK). Probably ideally you should use SDK's from the same time.

Comment: [TEXTMETRICA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-textmetrica) is declared in wingdi.h, which should be included by windows.h. Are you including windows.h before d3dx9.h?

Comment: Rup - its the first error I get, I include windows.h first. Also I know that its included in windows.h, I've been on the page you sent me already
Fire Lancer - 10.0.17763.0, Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Comment: OK, I'd look at wingdi.h and work out why you aren't getting the declaration then. There are a few #ifdefs around it - this is a normal desktop app not a UWP app?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the legacy DirectX SDK with VS 2015 or later, you need to make sure the DXSDK include/lib paths are *after* the standard Windows 8.1 SDK / Windows 10 SDK paths. This is because the legacy DirectX SDK has out-of-date copies of some Windows headers.

Details are covered at the bottom of [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-#using-directx-sdk-projects-with-visual-studio).

> DirectX 9 is very old, and really was only needed to target Windows XP. You should look at DirectX 11 instead, and in particular [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)'s `SpriteBatch`. See [Living without D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/).